# The noble truths and eight fold path aren't holy than a learner. when a learner becomes a teacher?

Tags: personal-practice

I want to accept the Noble Eightfold Path (somewhere it is 10). I know what I can do. I know how many positive possibilities are surging inside me to come out. I know I am all alone to mark my words by adapting everything that I say. By breathing and watching my beloved resting I feel so relaxed. I want to share this feeling with everyone.

Do I really need to devote my life to the Noble Eightfold Path? Life as it seems is not that bad, even without the Eightfold Path. Is it necessary to adapt whatever I read in Buddhism? Can one reciprocrate what he/she has never read before? (My English isn't much good, I am learning. I welcome you (especially Andrei with his best guess and Crab Bucket) if they can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '[Noble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_(Buddhism))' in the "[Noble eight-fold path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path)" is that you become a Noble one ([Arya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_(Buddhism))) by following it.

Comment: All of The nobel prize winners weren't following the eight fold path. They did exceptional good for world, many of them are really awesome. Why the followers of buddism are bound to eight fold path ? Why rules !

Comment: You are not bound and the Noble 8 Fold Path is not all about doing good. It is the way to get out of misery or stress. A Nobel prize winner may do good but he is not free from stress.

Comment: Ah, thats true.